# Why network with linear layers can't learn anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to build a neural network for binary classification, unfortunately it always predicts the value 0, even though one fifth of the training set data is 1. I have no idea why it is so. My dataset looks as this, so there are a couple of categorical variables and a couple of continuous, (target is the one we predict):

[image]

Here one can download the data:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PsG2rRdbxyocyqvLSa7zSy_aVDMRJ2Ug?usp=sharing

You can read it with

```
df = pd.read_csv("train.csv", index_col=0)
```

Now I am preparing the data for neural network:

```
x_train=df.drop(labels=['target'], axis=1).values
y_train=df['target'].values
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
x_train,
y_train,
test_size=0.2)

LR = 0.001 
EPOCH = 50
BATCH_SIZE = 64

torch_X_train = torch.tensor(X_train)
torch_y_train = torch.tensor(y_train)

torch_X_val = torch.tensor(X_val)
torch_y_val = torch.tensor(y_val)

train = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch_X_train,torch_y_train)
validate = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch_X_val,torch_y_val)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size = 
BATCH_SIZE, shuffle = True)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(validate, batch_size = 
BATCH_SIZE, shuffle = False)
```

And define a simple network with just linear layers:

```
class NN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_size):
    super().__init__()
    self.to_class=nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(input_size,512),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(512,256),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(256,32),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(32,2)
    )
def forward(self,inputs):
    pred= self.to_class(inputs)
    return F.softmax(pred, dim=1)
```

And lastly I train it

```
net=NN(7)


loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=LR)

train_loss = np.zeros(EPOCH)
val_loss = np.zeros(EPOCH)
acc_train = []
acc_val=[]

for epoch in range(EPOCH):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for data in train_loader:
        X, y = data
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output=net(X.float())
        total += output.size(0)
        pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
        correct += pred.eq(y.view_as(pred)).sum().item()
        loss = loss_func(output.squeeze(), y) 
        loss.backward()                     
        optimizer.step() 
        train_loss[epoch] += loss
    train_loss[epoch] /= len(train_loader)
    acc_train.append(correct/total*100)
print('epoch %d:\t train_accuracy %.5f\ttrain loss: %.5f'%(epoch,acc_train[epoch], train_loss[epoch]))
```

But the train loss is not going anywhere and the predictions are always one class! Can someone explain this phenomenon and hint how I can improve it?

[image]

Comment: please (always) post code as code, and data as something copy-pasteable. There is no way we can help you as it is right now.

Comment: Okay, I will edit, thought it might be a simple mistake

Comment: one thing that pops out is the `input_size->32->256->32->2`.  Why the bottleneck right after the input_size? Makes more sense to do something like `input_size->512->256->32->2`

Comment: I tried different setups, result is the same

Comment: It is edited now, the data is on google drive link I have shared.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [the doc](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html)

This is the standard training loop

```
for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        inputs, labels = data

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

It seems you are missing `optimizer.zero_grad()`.

Please try to add it and see how it does.

---

If this doesn't work, please use *the same* net on a different dataset, for example MNIST, directly downloaded  from pytorch. This net should be able to solve MNIST, so this way we can debug if the problem is the net or something related to the data or the labels.

---

Another thing is balancing the labels: if 80% are 0 and 20% are 1 (or vice versa) you may want to use [weighted cross entropy](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html)

---

Another thing you may want is leaky relu instead of relu. This prevents vanishing gradients for some problems.

Comment: You are right I forgot about it, but it didn't change the learning.  I used the same network on MINST and got 96% accuracy, that's why I thought it might work here.

Comment: So how do you think I might improve here if the net cant capture 1's from this data? I checked if all batches had 1's in them and around 1/5 of every batch is 1's.

Comment: Ok, if this works on MNIST, then the net is fine, and the problem is either the network doesn't have the capacity to learn the dataset (unlikely, but you can make the net much larger and see if there's an improvement), or more likely, the labels are somehow off. Maybe they are not correct? dirty? shuffled? Try to use the same net on the 1st 10 rows of the data, and see 100% accuracy. continue from there.

Comment: Another thing is balancing the labels: if 80% are 0 and 20% are 1 (or vice versa) you may want to use [weighted cross entropy](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html)

Comment: @ryszardeggink Another thing you may want is leaky relu instead of relu. This prevents vanishing gradients for some problems.

Comment: I applied all your suggestions, nothing works, it still predicts all 0's, even when I take as a training set only 64 rows which make it just one batch, which makes me wonder: is loss function good one for this problem? What I mean is that this loss function does not optimize accuracy.

Comment: Can you take only rows for which the label is 1 and tell what happened?

Comment: Finally it started predicting some 1's, I have no idea why, I only restarted whole notebook, thanks for your help!

Comment: @ryszardeggink I think it will be of value to understand what happened here, if you end up figuring out, please share! Also, consider accepting the answer if any suggestion was the right one.

Comment: funny thing, it worked well and now it is back to predicting one sided, I added some batch normalization and then it stopped predicting one class, but the results are not so great